# Make Navigation Full Height

Tags: html, css

How  would I be able to make the navigation on this test site the full height of the dark grey bar (header), and vertically centered? http://website-test-lab.com/sites/mfm/

You can see that the red background of the home link is not filling the dark grey bar area height wise.
The site including the menu is responsive.

EDIT: Apologies for the lack of code example but there is too much CSS involved to be added here or jsfiddle for example. If you could use Dev Tools/Firebug  that would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<header id="masthead" class="header clearfix" role="banner">

<!-- logo -->
  <div class="logo grid-15 tablet-grid-15">
   <a href="#">
    <img src="#/library/img/mfmlogo.jpg" alt="#" class="logo-img">
   </a>
  </div>
<!-- /logo -->

<!-- nav -->
  <nav id="header-menu" class="nav grid-85 tablet-grid-85" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav-list clearfix">
      <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-32 current_page_item menu-item-46"><a href="http://website-test-lab.com/sites/mfm/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47"><a href="http://website-test-lab.com/sites/mfm/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
<!-- /nav -->

</header>
```

CSS:

```
#masthead {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    background: #363737;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.logo {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I thought it would be easier to use Firebig or Dev tools to view the code and see what's going on. I can add some code; let me edit the post.

Comment: @HuwRowlands post your code to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Too much code for jsfiddle

Comment: I edited my answer, there was a mistake

Comment: please set this question to answered if it suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set margin-top for .nav as
`#masthead .nav{
margin-top:0px;
}`

and set padding like 
`#masthead .nav ul li a{
padding:31px 15px;
}`